# Grabbing Webcam Frame with OpenCV (latest) on Windows leads to Black image

Tags: python, windows, opencv, webcam

Fairly experienced with OpenCV, Python and Windows/Linux.
When trying to read a high-res (~8 MP) webcam image using CAP_DSHOW (nothing else works), at certain situations I get a black image with the right size. I mean zeros all along.

This happens either when there is too much light, the autofocus camera is too near to the object, or both.

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not talking about the displaying of the image. The image itself is zeros.

Comment: hardware defect is my bet. -- all you're gonna get is guesses. some may be good but nobody will _know_ what's going on. you are closest to the problem. you're the only one who can debug it.